# LiveCD/USB boot issues with Ubuntu 12.04 on blank drive

Tags: 12.04, installation, live-usb, live-cd

Not sure how common this issue is, or even how badly I may be missing something simple, but I am a first time user having some serious problems.

Some background: old HDD running Windows 7 developed too many bad sectors and is bricked. I'm attempting to install Ubuntu 12.04 on a fresh 1TB drive by booting from a LiveUSB.

I've not been able to get past the initial menu screen, however, as the process stalls out shortly after selecting an option (both boot from drive and install to drive). I've tried multiple USB drives as well as CDs, modified the boot order, flashed BIOS, and even tried booting with only the flash drive and the keyboard connected with the same results.

Typically what I observe is that the OS begins what I think is compiling, listing drivers and components before freezing on one. When the keyboard is plugged in, its the keyboard driver, before I flashed BIOS, it was a BIOS related item, now its an unknown entry.

The computer seems to be reading the drive (indicated by USB light flashing or CD drive reading) for roughly 10 minutes with no progress, followed by the drives going quiet.

Some spec info:

Motherboard: ASUS P5Q Pro,
BIOS version 2102 (latest version),
Intel chipset
CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo E8400 Wolfdale 3.0GHz

help would be appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times (using the LiveUSB in this example) the following helps:

As you mentioned you managed to see the boot menu. After selecting your language press <kbd>F6</kbd> and several options will appear:

[image]

Activate the **ACPI=OFF** option ONLY and test it with only that option.

If it still fails then activate the **NOAPIC** option ONLY and test it with that one.

If it still fails activate both options and test it out. Lastly if it still fails and you have pray to the gods, crossed your fingers and called for Linus Torvalds then use the 2 options again but add **NOLAPIC**.

Normally when I have your same problem, with the **ACPI=OFF** option is enough. Let me know how it went.

Comment: "then use the 2 options again but add NOLAPIC"
are these 2 separate tries, or one try with all the options ?

Comment: @josinalvo You can select them alone or have them all together via the menu that appears (As seen in the image above). Its up to you.